# Large uploaded images not resizing?

Tags: images, uploads

I'm uploading images of varying size, and am noticing that larger images are not resizing/scaling to smaller versions. The only one that was resized (below) is only about 9MB, and has (quite a few) resized versions.

Why are the larger images not resizing? This makes viewing them terrible, as they're 10-30+ MB each in cases. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which image size is not being resized? WP always keeps the original image in addition to the resized versions. Are you saying that the alternative image sizes simply don't exist? Please be more explicit/specific

Comment: It seems like larger files (I'm guessing over 10MB, but I don't know the cut-off) are NOT being resized automatically during upload, but smaller ones are. In this case, it seems like images only a couple MB and under get "scaled", meaning they're resized. Larger images, are not, and there is 1) no thumbnail, and 2) no medium/large scaled versions. 

In the case above, the "115631.jpg" image is only about 9MB, and it was scaled down (why there are a ton of versions, I do not know), but the larger images never get resized.

Comment: This results on thumbnails and any renderings of the images (such as those sized down in HTML) to render the full 12000x9000 image instead of a scaled version. I should not I'm able to still manually resize them when editing the image, but I don't know why this is not happening when uploading for all images.

Comment: Is this a host where you can check your log files? If so, I'd start by checking error logs for PHP and/or the webserver. I wonder if your large images are exhausting some resource or other (eg: memory).

Comment: Yes, I'm in full control of the server. I just need to figure out where the logs are.

Comment: We've had a similar case, the reason was too little memory. WP failed on importing / resizing 20MB+ images. As PatJ already said, you should find errors about this in your PHP / WP logs.

Comment: sounds like your server simply can't handle the larger sizes, the equivalent of taking too big a bite of food and struggling to swallow. PHP only gives you so much time and memory to do the work in, and servers have limited resources, if you upload huge images it may not be able to resize it

Comment: I cannot find anything in the logs...I've tried /var/log/php7.4-fpm.log, /var/log/nginx/error.log, and /var/log/nginx/access.log. Nothing indicating an error. I also enabled WP debugging but do not see debug.log at all inside the wp-content folder. I'm stumped!

Comment: I would recommend NOT uploading images that big... unless you're actually selling or giving people downloads of images that large, I can't see a justification for it.  That said, as @kero and Tom J Nowell suggested, I'm guessing your server is timing out because it's taking too long to process these images.